# How can I make this two scripts work together?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-sheets, automation, implementation

I have two codes that scrape a page that is basically a search engine. It reads information from the google sheet, searches on the URL, gets some info and then, writes them on the sheet.

The problem is that I'm using two codes, the second is the one that writes the info into the google sheet.

The first code is doing all the search and then when every search is finished the second one starts to write the fetched information into the google sheets.

What I wanna do is to search one and then write, search the second one and write..... I've tried different ways but that's my first code and my first time programming, so I'm struggling with that.

k_bot.py (Web Scraper)

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException
    
    import re
    import time
    
    
    class BOT(object):
        def __init__(self, cpfs):
    
            # SETUP FOR URL
            self.bot_url = 'http://www.3kplus.net/'
            self.cpfs = cpfs
    
            self.profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
            self.options = Options()
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=self.profile,
                                            executable_path='C:\\Users\MOISA\Documents\geckodriver.exe',
                                            options=self.options)
    
            # NAVIGATE TO URL
            self.driver.get(self.bot_url)
    
            login_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/input')
            login_box.send_keys('daiane')
    
            pass_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/input')
            pass_box.send_keys('789456')
    
            login_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/div[3]/div[2]/button')
            login_btn.click()
    
        def search_cpfs(self):
    
            # SEARCH THROUGH THE LIST OF CLIENT CODES (1ST COLUMN OF THE SPREADSHEET), AND OBTAIN THESE INFOS
            nomes = []
            idades = []
            beneficios = []
            concessoes = []
            salarios = []
            bancoss = []
            bancoscard = []
            consigs = []
            cards = []
    
            for cpf in self.cpfs:
                print(f"Procurando {cpf}.")
                self.driver.get(self.bot_url)
                self.delay = 3  # seconds
    
                # SEARCH CLIENT CODE
                try:
                    cpf_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[1]/input')
                    cpf_input.send_keys(cpf)
    
                    cpf_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[2]/button')
                    cpf_btn.click()
                    cpf_btn.click()
    
                    time.sleep(2)
    
                # CLIENT CODE IS VALID
                    # CLIENT CODE HAVE NOTIFICATION
                    if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="notification"]').is_displayed():
    
                        nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/h2").text
                        idade = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]").text
                        age = re.search(r'\((.*?)Anos', idade).group(1)
                        beneficio = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[5]/span/b   ").text
                        concessao = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
                        salario = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span").text
                        bancos = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loans"]').text
                        bancosw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancos)
                        bankslist = ', '.join(bancosw)
                        bancocard = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cards"]').text
                        bcardw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancocard)
                        bcardlist = ', '.join(bcardw)
                        consig = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
                        card = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span").text
    
                        print('CPF Valido')
                        print('NOTIFICACAO')
                        print(nome, age, beneficio, concessao, salario, bankslist, bcardlist, consig, card)
    
                    # CLIENT CODE DOESN'T HAVE NOTIFICATION
                    else:
                        nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
                        idade = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]").text
                        age = re.search(r'\((.*?)Anos', idade).group(1)
                        beneficio = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/span/b").text
                        concessao = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span").text
                        salario = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span").text
                        bancos = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loans"]').text
                        bancosw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancos)
                        bankslist = ', '.join(bancosw)
                        bancocard = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cards"]').text
                        bcardw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancocard)
                        bcardlist = ', '.join(bcardw)
                        consig = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
                        card = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                            "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span").text
    
                        print('CPF Valido')
                        print(nome, age, beneficio, concessao, salario, bankslist, bcardlist, consig, card)
    
                # IF THE CLIENT CODE IS WRONG
                except (NoSuchElementException, UnexpectedAlertPresentException):
                    nome = ''
                    idade = ''
                    age = ''
                    concessao = ''
                    salario = ''
                    bancos = ''
                    bancosw = ''
                    bankslist = ''
                    bancocard = ''
                    bcardw = ''
                    bcardlist = ''
                    consig = ''
                    card = ''
                    print('CPF Invalido')
    
                nomes.append(nome)
                idades.append(age)
                beneficios.append(beneficio)
                concessoes.append(concessao)
                salarios.append(salario)
                bancoss.append(bankslist)
                bancoscard.append(bcardlist)
                consigs.append(consig)
                cards.append(card)
    
            return nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards
```

cpf_updater.py (Info google sheet writer)

```py
    from k_bot import BOT
    import gspread
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
    import time
    from gspread.exceptions import APIError
    
    
    class CpfSearch(object):
        def __init__(self, spreadsheet_name):
            self.cpf_col = 1
            self.nome_col = 2
            self.age_col = 3
            self.beneficio_col = 4
            self.concessao_col = 5
            self.salario_col = 6
            self.bancos_col = 7
            self.bancocard_col = 9
            self.consig_col = 10
            self.card_col = 16
    
            scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
                     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
    
            creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('CONSULTAS.json', scope)
    
            client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    
            self.sheet = client.open(spreadsheet_name).sheet1
    
        def process_cpf_list(self):
    
            # SKIP OVER COLUMN HEADING IN THE SPREADSHEET
            cpfs = self.sheet.col_values(self.cpf_col)[1:]
    
            bot_url = BOT(cpfs)
            nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards = bot_url.search_cpfs()
    
            # UPDATE THE SHEET
            print("Atualizando...")
    
            for cpfs in range(len(nomes)):
                try:
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.nome_col, nomes[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.age_col, idades[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.beneficio_col, beneficios[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.concessao_col, concessoes[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.salario_col, salarios[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.bancos_col, bancoss[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.bancocard_col, bancoscard[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.consig_col, consigs[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.card_col, cards[cpfs])
                    print('Cliente atualizado!')
                except APIError:
                    print('Esperando para atualizar...')
                    time.sleep(100)
                    continue
    
    
    cpf_updater = CpfSearch('TESTE')
    cpf_updater.process_cpf_list()
```

EDIT k_bot.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException

import re
import time


class BOT(object):
    def __init__(self, cpfs):

        # SETUP FOR URL
        self.bot_url = 'http://www.3kplus.net/'
        self.cpfs = cpfs

        self.profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        self.options = Options()
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=self.profile,
                                        executable_path='C:\\Users\MOISA\Documents\geckodriver.exe',
                                        options=self.options)

        # NAVIGATE TO URL
        self.driver.get(self.bot_url)

        login_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/input')
        login_box.send_keys('daiane')

        pass_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/input')
        pass_box.send_keys('789456')

        login_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/div[3]/div[2]/button')
        login_btn.click()

    def search_cpfs(self, cpf):

        # SEARCH THROUGH THE LIST OF CLIENT CODES (1ST COLUMN OF THE SPREADSHEET), AND OBTAIN THESE INFOS
        nomes = []
        idades = []
        beneficios = []
        concessoes = []
        salarios = []
        bancoss = []
        bancoscard = []
        consigs = []
        cards = []

        print(f"Procurando {cpf}.")
        self.driver.get(self.bot_url)
        self.delay = 3  # seconds

        # SEARCH CLIENT CODE
        try:
            cpf_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[1]/input')
            cpf_input.send_keys(cpf)

            cpf_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[2]/button')
            cpf_btn.click()
            cpf_btn.click()

            time.sleep(2)

        # CLIENT CODE IS VALID
            # CLIENT CODE HAVE NOTIFICATION
            if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="notification"]').is_displayed():

                nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/h2").text
                idade = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]").text
                age = re.search(r'\((.*?)Anos', idade).group(1)
                beneficio = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[5]/span/b   ").text
                concessao = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
                salario = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span").text
                bancos = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loans"]').text
                bancosw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancos)
                bankslist = ', '.join(bancosw)
                bancocard = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cards"]').text
                bcardw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancocard)
                bcardlist = ', '.join(bcardw)
                consig = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
                card = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span").text

                print('CPF Valido')
                print('NOTIFICACAO')
                print(nome, age, beneficio, concessao, salario, bankslist, bcardlist, consig, card)

            # CLIENT CODE DOESN'T HAVE NOTIFICATION
            else:
                nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
                idade = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]").text
                age = re.search(r'\((.*?)Anos', idade).group(1)
                beneficio = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/span/b").text
                concessao = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span").text
                salario = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span").text
                bancos = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loans"]').text
                bancosw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancos)
                bankslist = ', '.join(bancosw)
                bancocard = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cards"]').text
                bcardw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancocard)
                bcardlist = ', '.join(bcardw)
                consig = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
                card = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span").text

                print('CPF Valido')
                print(nome, age, beneficio, concessao, salario, bankslist, bcardlist, consig, card)

        # IF THE CLIENT CODE IS WRONG
        except (NoSuchElementException, UnexpectedAlertPresentException):
            nome = ''
            idade = ''
            age = ''
            concessao = ''
            salario = ''
            bancos = ''
            bancosw = ''
            bankslist = ''
            bancocard = ''
            bcardw = ''
            bcardlist = ''
            consig = ''
            card = ''
            print('CPF Invalido')

        nomes.append(nome)
        idades.append(age)
        beneficios.append(beneficio)
        concessoes.append(concessao)
        salarios.append(salario)
        bancoss.append(bankslist)
        bancoscard.append(bcardlist)
        consigs.append(consig)
        cards.append(card)

        return nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards
```

EDIT cpf_updater.py

```
from k_bot import BOT
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import time
from gspread.exceptions import APIError


class CpfSearch(object):
    def __init__(self, spreadsheet_name):
        self.cpf_col = 1
        self.nome_col = 2
        self.age_col = 3
        self.beneficio_col = 4
        self.concessao_col = 5
        self.salario_col = 6
        self.bancos_col = 7
        self.bancocard_col = 9
        self.consig_col = 10
        self.card_col = 16

        scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
                 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']

        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('CONSULTAS.json', scope)

        client = gspread.authorize(creds)

        self.sheet = client.open(spreadsheet_name).sheet1

    def process_cpf_list(self):

        # SKIP OVER COLUMN HEADING IN THE SPREADSHEET
        cpfs = self.sheet.col_values(self.cpf_col)[1:]

        bot_url = BOT()
        for cpf in self.cpfs:
            nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards = bot_url.search_cpfs()

            # UPDATE THE SHEET
            print("Atualizando...")

            for cpfs in range(len(nomes)):
                try:
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.nome_col, nomes[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.age_col, idades[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.beneficio_col, beneficios[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.concessao_col, concessoes[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.salario_col, salarios[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.bancos_col, bancoss[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.bancocard_col, bancoscard[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.consig_col, consigs[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.card_col, cards[cpfs])
                    self.sheet.add_rows(self.sheet)
                    print('Cliente atualizado!')
                except APIError:
                    print('Esperando para atualizar...')
                    time.sleep(100)
                    continue


cpf_updater = CpfSearch('TESTE')
cpf_updater.process_cpf_list()
```

Comment: don't use `for cpf in self.cpfs:` inside `def search_cpfs(self):` but run it with single element - `search_cpfs(self, cpf):` and use this loop `for cpf in self.cpfs:` in `process_cpf_list(self):` to run `search_cpfs(self, cpf):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly: you should move `for cpf in self.cpfs:` from first script to second script.

---

In first script you should have function

```
def search_cpfs(self, cpf):
```

which searchs only for one `cpf`.

So you have to remove `for cpf in self.cpfs:` from `search_cpfs()` and run `Bot()` without `cpfs` but use single `cpf` when your run `search_cpfs()`.

In second script you should use this `for`-loop to run `search_cpfs(cpf)` with different values

```
    bot_url = BOT()

    for cpf in cpfs:
       ...variables... = bot_url.search_cpfs(cpf)

       # UPDATE THE SHEET
       print("Atualizando...")
```

---

**EDIT:**

In `class BOT()` you have to use `__init__(self)` without `cpfs` and without `self.cpfs = cpfs`

Because `search_cpfs(self, cpf):` search for only one item then you may use name `search_cpf` without `s` (but it not mandatory) and you don't need lists

```
    nomes = []
    idades = []
    beneficios = []
    concessoes = []
    salarios = []
    bancoss = []
    bancoscard = []
    consigs = []
    cards = []
```

but you can return directly results

```
return nome, idade, beneficio, concessoe, salario, bancos, bancocard, consig, card
```

---

In `process_cpf_list` you have to join two `for`-loops

```
for cpf in cpfs:
    # code 1
    nomes = ...

    for cpfs in range(len(nomes)):
        # code 2
        self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.nome_col, nomes[cpfs])
```

to create one `for`-loop

```
for row, cpf in enumerate(cpfs): 
    # code 1
    nomes, idades, ... = BOT.search_cpfs()

    # code 2
    self.sheet.update_cell(row + 2, self.nome_col, nomes[row])
    self.sheet.update_cell(row + 2, self.age_col, idades[row])
```

I will use name `row` instead of second `cpfs` to make it more readable.

Becuse `search_cpfs` gives me list with single result (instead of list of lists) then I can use `nome` instead of `nomes[cpfs]` and then I can use `row = row + 2`

```
for row, cpf in enumerate(cpfs): 
    # code 1
    nome, idade, ... = BOT.search_cpfs(cpf)

    # code 2
    row = row + 2
    self.sheet.update_cell(row, self.nome_col, nome)
    self.sheet.update_cell(row, self.age_col, idade)
```

I could even use `enumerate(cpfs, 2)` instead of `row = row + 2`

---

Full code - didn't test it

**k_bot.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException

import re
import time


class BOT(object):

    def __init__(self): 

        # SETUP FOR URL
        self.bot_url = 'http://www.3kplus.net/'

        self.profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        self.options = Options()
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=self.profile,
                                        executable_path='C:\\Users\MOISA\Documents\geckodriver.exe',
                                        options=self.options)

        # NAVIGATE TO URL
        self.driver.get(self.bot_url)

        login_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/input')
        login_box.send_keys('daiane')

        pass_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/input')
        pass_box.send_keys('789456')

        login_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/div[3]/div[2]/button')
        login_btn.click()

    def search_cpf(self, cpf):

        print(f"Procurando {cpf}.")
        self.driver.get(self.bot_url)
        self.delay = 3  # seconds

        # SEARCH CLIENT CODE
        try:
            cpf_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[1]/input')
            cpf_input.send_keys(cpf)

            cpf_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[2]/button')
            cpf_btn.click()
            cpf_btn.click()

            time.sleep(2)

            # CLIENT CODE IS VALID
            # CLIENT CODE HAVE NOTIFICATION
            if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="notification"]').is_displayed():

                nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/h2").text
                idade = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]").text
                age = re.search(r'\((.*?)Anos', idade).group(1)
                beneficio = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[5]/span/b   ").text
                concessao = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
                salario = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span").text
                bancos = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loans"]').text
                bancosw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancos)
                bankslist = ', '.join(bancosw)
                bancocard = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cards"]').text
                bcardw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancocard)
                bcardlist = ', '.join(bcardw)
                consig = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
                card = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span").text

                print('CPF Valido')
                print('NOTIFICACAO')
                print(nome, age, beneficio, concessao, salario, bankslist, bcardlist, consig, card)

            # CLIENT CODE DOESN'T HAVE NOTIFICATION
            else:
                nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
                idade = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]").text
                age = re.search(r'\((.*?)Anos', idade).group(1)
                beneficio = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/span/b").text
                concessao = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span").text
                salario = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span").text
                bancos = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loans"]').text
                bancosw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancos)
                bankslist = ', '.join(bancosw)
                bancocard = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cards"]').text
                bcardw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancocard)
                bcardlist = ', '.join(bcardw)
                consig = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
                card = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span").text

                print('CPF Valido')
                print(nome, age, beneficio, concessao, salario, bankslist, bcardlist, consig, card)

        # IF THE CLIENT CODE IS WRONG
        except (NoSuchElementException, UnexpectedAlertPresentException):
            nome = ''
            idade = ''
            age = ''
            concessao = ''
            salario = ''
            bancos = ''
            bancosw = ''
            bankslist = ''
            bancocard = ''
            bcardw = ''
            bcardlist = ''
            consig = ''
            card = ''
            print('CPF Invalido')

         return nome, idade, beneficio, concessoe, salario, bancos, bancocard, consig, card
```

**cpf_updater.py**

```
from k_bot import BOT
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import time
from gspread.exceptions import APIError


class CpfSearch(object):

    def __init__(self, spreadsheet_name):
        self.cpf_col = 1
        self.nome_col = 2
        self.age_col = 3
        self.beneficio_col = 4
        self.concessao_col = 5
        self.salario_col = 6
        self.bancos_col = 7
        self.bancocard_col = 9
        self.consig_col = 10
        self.card_col = 16

        scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
                 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']

        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('CONSULTAS.json', scope)

        client = gspread.authorize(creds)

        self.sheet = client.open(spreadsheet_name).sheet1

    def process_cpf_list(self):

        # SKIP OVER COLUMN HEADING IN THE SPREADSHEET
        cpfs = self.sheet.col_values(self.cpf_col)[1:]

        bot_url = BOT()

        for row, cpf in enumerate(cpfs): # if you use `enumerate(cpfs, 2)` then you don't need `row = row + 2`
            #old version gives many results 
            # nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards = bot_url.search_cpfs()

            # new version gives only one result
            nome, idade, beneficio, concessoe, salario, bancos, bancocard, consig, card = bot_url.search_cpfs(cpf)

            # UPDATE THE SHEET
            print("Atualizando...")

            try:
                row = row + 2
                self.sheet.update_cell(row, self.nome_col, nome)
                self.sheet.update_cell(row, self.age_col, idade)
                self.sheet.update_cell(row, self.beneficio_col, beneficio)
                self.sheet.update_cell(row, self.concessao_col, concessoe)
                self.sheet.update_cell(row, self.salario_col, salario)
                self.sheet.update_cell(row, self.bancos_col, bancos)
                self.sheet.update_cell(row, self.bancocard_col, bancocard)
                self.sheet.update_cell(row, self.consig_col, consig)
                self.sheet.update_cell(row, self.card_col, card)
                print('Cliente atualizado!')
            except APIError:
                print('Esperando para atualizar...')
                time.sleep(100)
                continue


cpf_updater = CpfSearch('TESTE')
cpf_updater.process_cpf_list()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Furas! I'm trying implement this but I'm struggling a little bit... Could you please take a look of how my code Is now? I'v updated the but, know It's wrong but I tried to do what you said :)

Comment: I added the edited codes on the botton of my question :) Hugs from Brazil

Comment: you have to join line `for cpf in self.cpfs:` with `for cpfs in range(len(nomes)):` to create something like `for cpfs, cpf in enumerate(self.cpfs:)`. I will create full code.

Comment: and in BOT you have to use `def __init__(self):` without `cpfs`. And remove `self.cpfs = cpfs`

Comment: I added full code But I didn't test it - I don't have spreadsheets with data. Hugs from Poland :)

Comment: Thank you so much Furas, It worked like a charm!! Thanks for your help :)